# Should I filter records in a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm a beginner at asp.net mvc, I'm building a web app where users can see who they owe money to, who owes money to them etc...

So now I'm curious where in my project should I filter the records for my database.

Lets say that I want to show how much money a user owes grouped by the names of users he owes it to.

This is my view model that I pass to the view:

```
public IEnumerable<Dug> Dugovanja { get; set; }
public Korisnik Korisnik { get; set; }
```

So the question is, should i filter the records from the database to show the grouped by result in the view directly, using methods in the view model (which I read was wrong) and simply calling them from the view, or should I add another property to the view model that would represent the filtered results and populate it in the controller?

The easiest way seems to be to filter them in the view directly, but then what if I have to use the same filtered results multiple times in the view?

Edit:

My debt class:

```
public class Dug
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column("Duznik")]
        public int DuznikId { get; set; }
        [Column("Vjerovnik")]
        public int VjerovnikId { get; set; }
        public decimal Iznos { get; set; }
        public string Opis { get; set; }
        public DateTime Datum { get; set; }
        public decimal Uplata { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Datum_Uplate { get; set; }
        public bool Zatvoreno { get; set; }

        public virtual Korisnik Duznik { get; set; }
        public virtual Korisnik Vjerovnik { get; set; }
    }
```

User class:

```
 public class Korisnik
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Ime { get; set; }
        public string Lozinka  { get; set; }
    }
```

User = Korisnik, Duznik = person who owes money, Vjerovnik = person to whom user owes money

Comment: Are you using any ORM such as EF?

Comment: @AdnanNiloy yes I'm using entity framework

Comment: No - the view is just that - a "view" of your data. Avoid putting logic in there. Having a property for the filtered data in your ViewModel is a valid approach.

Comment: can you please post the code for your models(i.e Debts, User)?

Comment: @AdnanNiloy I edited the question to include it, it's in my native language tho so sorry but it would take too much time to translate

Comment: @TeodorKurtev can you point me in the direction of how I would add that property, what type would it be etc, it's pretty confusing to me

Comment: You can take a look at this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

The simplest workflow is this:
1. Create a ViewModel class that only has the properties you need to display
2. Get the database models that hold that data you want to display
3. Convert the database models to VMs
4. Send the VM to the View

That's it. Now what the type of the properties are going to be - that's up to you and what data you want displayed.

Comment: @TeodorKurtev nice, thanks a lot!